# Use Jython and lint on VScode

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code, jython, lint, pylint

I would like to use Pylint to lint Jython code. 
Clearly, all Java functions (`JPanel`, `JFrame`, `JComboBox`, etc.) are recognized as an error (eg. `undefined variable 'JPanel'`).
I would like to know if there was a way to disable the *undefined variable* rule on VScode.
Or better yet, if an external Jython linter existed, it would be optimal! Because I have seen that there are no extensions for VSCode for Jython, unfortunately, and of course not even on the linting of jython code.

If none of the things listed above were possible, I would be happy to use another editor with linting, shorcut for self-formatting, etc.
In short, the essential of VScode!

**EDIT**
Based on a small experience of development in Angular it would be optimal to be able to put a pylinting file of Python 2.7 (since jython 3 doesn't exist) inside the project folder, exactly at the same way as it is done with `tslint.json`, and customize it by excluding for example the java functions. 

I hope there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jython runs on Java (and not Python), you should use a Java Linting utility instead of Pylint. It will read in the import on the top of your document (`import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;`) and (ideally) follow it to know all available methods and global variables exposed by Jython.
For linting Java, there are many options out there. You could try [checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/), [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [javac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac) bundled as a linter. Since you're using VSCode, you might want to try [Checkstyle (VSCode Marketplace)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shengchen.vscode-checkstyle), [Java(c) Linter (VSCode Marketplace)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=faustinoaq.javac-linter) or the official Eclipse-based [Red Hat Java Language Support Extension (VSCode Marketplace)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) which includes Linting amongst other features.
Most of these extensions can be configured over a `settings.json` file in a `.vscode` directory from your project root.